# Javascript image swap not working with IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a simple script that swaps an image in a div when you click on a thumbnail image. Like an image gallery. Works perfectly in IE 9 and above and in chrome firefox and so on. Just not in IE8 It will swap the image 1 or 2 times then it just stops working. I got this script off another forum, and I am a novice when it comes to scripts. I would appreciate any advice. this is the javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.thumbnail').live("click", function() {
        $('#mainImage').hide();
        $('#imageWrap').css('background-image', "url('images/main/ajax-loader.gif')");
        var i = $('<img />').attr('src',this.href).load(function() {
            $('#mainImage').attr('src', i.attr('src'));
            $('#imageWrap').css('background-image', 'none');
            $('#mainImage').fadeIn();
        });
        return false; 
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is the html

```
<div id="imageWrap">
<img src="images/main/blue.JPG" alt="Main Image" id="mainImage"/>
</div>
<!-- thumbnails are links to the full size image -->
<a href="images/main/blue.JPG" class="thumbnail"><img src="images/main/blue_thumb.JPG" alt="Image 1"/></a>
<a href="images/main/green.JPG" class="thumbnail"><img src="images/main/green_thumb.JPG" alt="Image 2"/></a>
<a href="images/main/red.JPG" class="thumbnail"><img src="images/main/red_thumb.JPG" alt="Image 3"/></a>
<a href="images/main/purple.JPG" class="thumbnail"><img src="images/main/purple_thumb.JPG" alt="Image 4"/></a>
```

and the css

```
#imageWrap {
width: 640px;
height: 510px;
background: url(../../images/main/ajax-loader.gif) center center no-repeat;
```

}

here is the link to the sample I have up.

http://www.rkshootingsupply.com/test

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're setting the source of the image before adding the event listener. When the `src` is changed for the first time it is requested from the server and this takes a bit of time; meaning that the event listener has chance to be attached before the image loads and subsequently triggers the load event. Then when you load the image the next time, IE fetches the image from its local cache and the load event is triggered before the event is attached. This will result in the JavaScript not knowing that the image has loaded and thus not updating it on the page.

Here is the modified code which changes the source after the event listener is attached.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.thumbnail').live("click", function() {
        $('#mainImage').hide();
        $('#imageWrap').css('background-image', "url('images/main/ajax-loader.gif')");
        var i = $('<img />').load(function() {
            $('#mainImage').attr('src', i.attr('src'));
            $('#imageWrap').css('background-image', 'none');
            $('#mainImage').fadeIn();
        }).attr('src',this.href);
        return false; 
    });
});
```

Comment: Now I am getting an error, says " line 17 char 13 i is null or not an object code 0" any ideas? @Ryan